# How to conditionally write the output from a bash scrip to another file?

Tags: bash

How can I write the output of a bash script to another file based on a condition in the script? for example, I need something like this

```
writeToFile=false

read -p "Enter (1-4): "
echo "foo"

if [ $REPLY == "1" ]; then
  echo "writing to file"
  writeToFile=true
fi
```

if they enter 1, then it should write everything that was outputted to a file. If not, then nothing should be written to a file.

From my research it seem like using tee is the correct way to go, but I cant figure out how to structure it. I have tried ending the file in | tee like so,

```
{
...
} | tee -a file.txt
```

but that writes everything every time. If I do

```
{
...
} |
if [ "$writeToFile" = true ]; then
  tee -a $(date +%F).txt
fi
```

however that does not work. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional `exec` along with process substitution.

```
if [[ "$writeToFile" == true ]]
then
    exec > >(tee -a "$file")
fi
```

All the output after this will be written to the `tee` process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
file='/dev/null'
if [[ "$writeToFile" == true ]]; then
  file='file.txt'
fi

{
...
} | tee -a "$file"
```

## edit

@Charles Duffy: thanks for pointing it out

Comment: The POSIX spec for `tee` explicitly requires it to treat `-` as a filename; any compliant copy is creating a file `./-` when called as described. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tee.html: *If a file operand is '-', it shall refer to a file named -; implementations shall not treat it as meaning standard output*

Comment: ...consider changing to `file=''` for initialization, and then using `tee ${file:+ -a "$file" }` to only pass the argument at all when nonempty.

Comment: thank you Diego and Charles, I think this is exactly what I need. However, it is failing to create a file. I can verify that the variable file is being set to file.txt, but something is going wrong with the tee command. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Try `file='/tmp/file.txt'` or another directory where you can write

Comment: whenever I try to tee a variable like `tee -a "$file"` it does not work. However `tee -a "file.txt"` does work. I did also try the above suggestion 
`tee ${file:+ -a "$file" }`. Why does using tee with a variable not work?

Comment: what's the OS? Can you write where you think you can? Have you used `set -x` to see what's happening? `tee` does not see any variable as it's expanded by `bash` before.

Comment: So, if `tee -a /tmp/file.txt` works, then `file='/tmp/file.txt; tee -a "$file"` should work